# PIC18f2520 + HCSR04

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, proximitysensor

I'm developing one simple code of HC SR04 for PIC18f2520 for received values in cm.  The situation is, I'm receiving the wrongs values and not change with the approximation. The sensor give values ​​that do not make sense.
I'm using a internal crystal 8Mhz, a TIMER1 with 16bit,1:8 prescaler and TMR1CS =0
= Internal clock (FOSC/4). The delay of ms and us is the compiler code. And the  TRIGER pin is RA2 and the ECHO pin is RA5. Someone  can help me?

```
#define TRIG RA2
#define echo RA5

void main(void)
{
   unsigned char duraca=0,duraca1=0,duraca2=0,duraca3=0;
   unsigned char distanci=0;
   int i;

   Config_micro();
   serialBegin();
   TRIG=0;
   TMR1L=0;
   TMR1H=0;
   while(1)
   {
      TRIG=1;
      DelayUs(10);
      TRIG=0;

      while(echo==1);
      TMR1ON = 1;
      while(echo==0);
      TMR1ON = 0;

      duraca1=(TMR1L+(TMR1H<<8));
      duraca2=(duracao1<<2);
      distanci=((duraca1)/58);
      printf("distancia: %2d cm\n\r",distanci);
      __delay_ms(90);
      __delay_ms(90);
      __delay_ms(90);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that you want to store more data in a variable that can't contain that much data

```
duraca1=(TMR1L+(TMR1H<<8));
```

duraca1 is defined as `unsigned char duraca1=0;` so it is only 8 bits wide.
by shifting TMR1H by 8, you get out of range.
since that one isn't correct, the folowing are also not correct.
try `unsigned short duraca=0,duraca1=0,duraca2=0,duraca3=0;`
instead of `unsigned char duraca=0,duraca1=0,duraca2=0,duraca3=0;`
a short is 16 bits wide and should solve your problem.